# Page showing padding/margins on left and right of content

Tags: c#, css, xaml, winui-3, powerbi-embedded

I'm very new to desktop development. I'm building a simple winui 3 app that has a webview2 page which essentially iframes a Power Bi Embedded Page. The PBI page uses the typical client secret from AAD to authenticate against PBI and uses an Azure PBI Embedded service that is linked to my workspace. The page itself has no padding/margins or columns, so the content being surfaced is good. But within the Winui app it seems a column/space is being put on the left and right of my viewport. Also the top app bar is double it's size. Any idea what properties to set/where?

I've tried every property I can on Google but maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing. Like I said, I'm still fresh at this.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information? I cannot reproduce with [Get started with WebView2 in WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK) apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I initially used Template Studio for WINUI to create the project. When i browsed your link it made me think that maybe i should try to create it from a blank WINUI project. Which worked perfectly, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to some [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview) properties for example Margin. See [Alignment, margin, padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/alignment-margin-padding#margin-and-padding) and [microsoft-ui-xaml/dev
/NavigationView](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/df0800178657c470eb9f25ef185ce906e8da3279/dev/NavigationView).

[image: margin and padding]
The image is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/images/xaml-layout-margins-padding.svg

There's also a document, [Get started with WebView2 in WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK) apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui), for beginners.